# Why can ps know about the process that runs after it?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ps

```
[root@myvm1 ~]# ps aux | grep ls
root     13594  0.0  0.1   3912   672 pts/1    R+   09:46   0:00 grep ls
```

In the above, the `ps aux` runs first and its output is then redirected to the `grep ls` command. The `grep ls` command runs after `ps aux`.

So why can `ps` know about the process that runs after it and has it in its output?

Comment: While `grep` can't process any output until after it's created, the `grep` *process* can be created either before or after the `ps` process. There's no special reason it has to be one way or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the above, the `ps aux` runs first and its output is then redirected to the `grep ls` command. The `grep ls` command runs after `ps aux`.
>
> So why can `ps` know about the process that runs after it and has it in its output?

You are writing about a logical order of command sequencing.

If you get insights in bash proceedings you get to know that both commands and the piping framework may be created in an order that does not really matter.

Moreover the piping framework is most probably a command output redirection.

Your answer is: the command `ps` is run actually after the process that will run `grep` has been created.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer, I have find another answer that explains this in more detail: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run